# Elastic Agent ECK not receiving logs from GCP PubSub Topic

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

i have created Elasticsearch Cluster along with the Fleet and Elastic Agent in ECK under GCP Project. The objective is to send the firewall and load balancer logs to Elastic Agent so it can be seen in the Kibana Dashboard, i am using GCP integration under the Kibana integration menu and have successfully assigned the policy to the agents.

However, i cannot see the log source and fields that supposed to inserted from the GCP integration related with the load balancing and firewall rules. One think i maybe missing is the JSON credential file for my service account as i still not found a way to insert the json credential into the agent container, my question is the json credential mandatory am i missing something? Hope someone can help me about this problem.